# Is there a way to clone services configurations in a cluster?

Tags: ansible, cluster-computing, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-manager, cluster-manager

I need to clone services configuration (hue, spark, etc.) from a cluster to another one. Both of cluster are managed by Cloudera Manager (i need to clone cloudera manager configuration too).

Comment: You can export and import CDH cluster template https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/6/6.3/topics/install_cluster_template.html but it only works for CDH components, not for CM services. I found it very useful for provisioning multiple environments (DEV, PROD), but is is not well documented.

Comment: I need to do exactly the same thing (multiple environments DEV, PROD). Is there other documentation in addition to docs.cloudera? (Such as some examples or something else)

Comment: I do not know why previous URL stopped work, try this https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/6/6.3/topics/cm_intro_api.html#concept_dnn_cr5_mr__section_ztf_lyt_xr or this https://cloudera.github.io/cm_api/apidocs/v19/path__cm_deployment.html

Comment: In this way can I clone a cluster or just Backing Up and Restoring on the same cluster?

Comment: If they are the same sized, you only need to change host ranges in "instantiator" section. And provide all the passwords of course. Here is some example of temple, what I found https://gist.github.com/jkestelyn/a0b84f7a51fa7444480c592e3369b30c

Comment: what if the size is different?

Comment: Then you also need to edit `hostTemplates` section and map used services to new instances.

Comment: In `hostTemplate` section there are 4 entrys, but each one have `"cardinality" : 0`. What does it mean?

Comment: Number of servers with the same installed services. You should change it according to your environment.

Comment: Ok thank you. In `variables` section should I change hosts name for databases or not?

Comment: If something in that sections differs between environments, you should also change it.